# wpf treeview with custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to show datas in Treeview like this :(*1)

```
 - There are 2 tickets 
   -- Opening problem category with ID 5685
   -- Closing problem category with ID 5687
 - There are 3 projects
   -- WPF project with ID 1234
   -- C# project with ID 12345
   -- ASP.NET project with ID 12
```

`Tickets`, `Projects` classes inherited from `EntityBase` class

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        public int EntityID { get; set; }
        public static EntityCollection entityCollection { get; set; }
        public EntityBase() 
        {
            entityCollection = new EntityCollection();
        }
    }
```

EntityCollection has private `List<EntityBase>` data.

To make parent nodes of projects or tickets, I created `TreeViewParentNode` class

```
    public class TreeViewParentNode
        {
            public string ParentName { get; set; }
            public List<EntityBase> ParentItems;
            public int ParentCount;
            public TreeViewParentNode(string ParentName) 
            {
                ParentCount = 0;
                this.ParentName = ParentName;
                ParentItems = new List<EntityBase>();
            }
 }
```

I have created a collection to show data in `Treeview` `ObservableCollection<TreeViewParentNode>` 
The Window's constructor:

```
 public ReminderExtendedWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            List<TreeViewParentNode> Nodes = new List<TreeViewParentNode>();
            foreach (EntityBase EntityItem in EntityBase.entityCollection)
            {
               TreeViewParentNode findnode = Nodes.Find(
                   delegate(TreeViewParentNode node) 
                   { 
                       return node.ParentName == EntityItem.GetType().Name; 
                   }
                   );
               if (findnode == null)
               {
                   TreeViewParentNode NewParentNode = new TreeViewParentNode(EntityItem.GetType().Name);
                   NewParentNode.ParentItems.Add(EntityItem);
                   NewParentNode.ParentCount++;
                   Nodes.Add(NewParentNode);
               }
               else
               {
                   findnode.ParentItems.Add(EntityItem);
                   findnode.ParentCount++;
               }
            }
            Coll = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewParentNode>(Nodes);
            DataContext = this;

        }
```

Treeview **XAML** codes

```
<TreeView Height="500" Width="375" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,50,0,0" 
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" x:Name="EntityTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Coll}">
```

What should I do to display datas like showed in above(*1) ?

Comment: You should model the association the other way around: Each parent should have multiple children, not each child multiple parents.

Comment: TreeViewParentNode class provides that situation. Each children is added to a parent, whose 'Name' property is copied from children's GetType().Name property. if (findnode == null) 'findnode' code block is constructing 'Each parent have multiple children' list.

Comment: Why are you doing it in such a complex way? Why even have a list of parents? It doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: Because there is no one parent. As I say in the question, there is one Tickets parent and one Projects parent.

Comment: Each node in a tree can have exactly one parent. That's how a tree view works. Therefore you should model your view model like this.